# Who gave the definition of rank in the von Neumann universe

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, math-history

In the von Neumann universe (cumulative hierarchy), the rank function $R(x)$ is defined as the least ordinal $\alpha$ that $x\in V_{\alpha +1}$ (or equivalently $x\subset V_{\alpha}$). I'd like to know who gave this definition and when.

I believe that this rank should not be credited to Mirimanoff because in his 1917 paper, Mirimanoff only gave a vague idea of rank and there was no von Neumann universe at that time.

I heard that the von Neumann universe was first presented in 1930 by Zermelo. However, I have not read his paper and am not sure if Zermelo gave this definition of rank.

Comment: You can find it into : Ernst Zermelo, [Collected Works. Vol I : Set Theory (ed.Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus & Akihiro Kanamori, Springer, 2010)](https://books.google.it/books?id=XB2nd2ovakIC&printsec=frontcover), **On boundary numbers and domains of sets. New investigations in the
foundations of set theory** (1930), page 401-on.

Comment: @MathWizard: The book is a "parallel translation" - the original language on even-numbered pages, and English on odd-numbered pages.   Everything is translated as far as I can tell. It's normal that you can't read the entire book on Google Books because copyright - the natural next step is to try to get it from a library.